# File exists check does not work

Tags: java, file-exists

This is my code:

```
String path = "/src/cst/org/main/data/data.txt";
    File f = new File( path );
    if( f.exists() ) { 
        yesorno = true;
        System.out.println( "File exists: " + yesorno );
    } else {
        yesorno = false;
        System.out.println( "File does not exist: " + yesorno );
    }
```

When I run this I always get "File does not exist..." even though the file exists for sure. And if I type the full path (C:/User/....) it works but I want to let it work by shorting the code.

I know this path works actually because on another class the method finds my pictures (.png). Do I have to add something because it's a .txt?

Comment: If you type `/src/...` it is an absolute path... On a Windows machine, it is guaranteed _not_ to exist.

Comment: But when I remove `/src/` it still can't find my file D:

Comment: @fge: Actually, no. It will take an absolute path *on the current drive*. It could exist - but it won't be "C:\Users\...", unless there are junctions involved.

Comment: @fge: Not necessarily; that would match `C:\src\...`.

Comment: Are you sure you know what your executing directory is?  If you're using an IDE, I'd be sure to check that.  Eclipse has tripped me up a few times with that.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Something wierd with *getClass().getResource("").toString()* the output starts with : `file:/....`, why?

Comment: @Azad: Not sure why you mentioned that to me... but asking for an empty string as a resource is an odd thing to do to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because you are not doning it correct, you want to give a full path to the file.

Use :

```
String path=getClass().getResource("/path/to/file").toString().replace("file:/", "");
```

Comment: This returns a path relative to the class used.  This might not work either.

Comment: This should work, as the *text* file placed inside one of your packages. I just tried to do so and it's worked, maybe you're not doing it correct.

Comment: But it doesn't work: `String path = getClass().getResource("/cst/org/main/data/data.txt").toString();
  File f = new File( path );`

Comment: Code: `String path = getClass().getResource("/cst/org/main/data/data.txt").toString();
  System.out.println( path );
`       And output: file:/C:/Users/Jannis/workspace/CST-ChampionSelectionTool/bin/cst/org/main/data/data.txt

Comment: @ColdStormy: I got the same problem, see the edited answer, this should work.

Comment: I would *not* do this. You're *assuming* that the resource is actually a file resource to start with. Given that `getResource` will return `null` if the resource doesn't exist, I'd just use that... and to *read* the resource, use `getResourceAsStream`...